# kubernetes (1.23) Failed to authenticate with Keycloak (21.0.2) OIDC

Tags: keycloak

First of all I am very new to Keycloak and excuse me if something I am asking might be wrong.

I'm trying to interface with Keycloak (21.0.2) in kubernetes (1.23)

I did the test based on the following blog, and I also modified the script to get the token，Is it a problem with my setup of the kube-config file?

https://medium.com/@charled.breteche/kind-keycloak-securing-kubernetes-api-server-with-oidc-371c5faef902

```bash
#!/bin/bash

curl -k -X POST \
 https://keycloak.keycloak.svc.cluster.local/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token  \
 -H 'Accept: application/json'  \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 -H 'cache-control: no-cache'  \
 -d "grant_type=password&username=$1&password=$1&client_id=kube&client_secret=kube-client-secret" > /tmp/token
 
 ACCESS_TOKEN=`cat /tmp/token | jq -r '.access_token'`
 REFRESH_TOKEN=`cat /tmp/token | jq -r '.refresh_token'`
 CA_DATA=$(cat /etc/kubernetes/pki/keycloakca.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n')
 
 kubectl config set-credentials $1 \
    --auth-provider=oidc \
    --auth-provider-arg=client-id=kube \
    --auth-provider-arg=client-secret=kube-client-secret \
    --auth-provider-arg=idp-issuer-url=https://keycloak.keycloak.svc.cluster.local/realms/master \
    --auth-provider-arg=access-token=$ACCESS_TOKEN \
    --auth-provider-arg=refresh-token=$REFRESH_TOKEN \
    --auth-provider-arg=idp-certificate-authority-data=$CA_DATA
 
kubectl config set-context $1 --cluster=nebula-cluster --user=$1
```